# NSubstitute: Mocking properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I created substitutes for `Person` and `AddressBook` classes in the unit Test.
The `AddressBook` class contains properties of type `Person` and name: `SamplePerson`.

```
public interface IAddressBook
{
    Person SamplePerson { get; set; }
}

public class AddressBook : IAddressBook
{
    public Person SamplePerson { get; set; }

    public AddressBook(Person samplePerson)
    {
        SamplePerson = samplePerson;
    }
}

public interface IPerson
{
    string GetName(string name);
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string GetName(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public void TestMethod1()
{
    var personMock = Substitute.For<IPerson>();
    var addressBookMock = Substitute.For<IAddressBook>();

    addressBookMock.SamplePerson.Returns(personMock); //not working
    addressBookMock.SamplePerson = personMock; //not working
    addressBookMock.SamplePerson = (Person)personMock; //not working

    Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
}
```

I would like to assign mock variable of `Person` type to **propeties** of mock variable of type `AddressBook`.

Is this possible?

Comment: `SamplePerson` property returns `Person` and not `IPerson` so your attempt to return `IPerson` will not work. Either mock the class or return an actual instance.

Comment: But it is impossible to mock Class using NSubsitute. I am receiving: ,,Could not find a parameterless contructor".

Comment: Either mock the `Person` class or return an actual instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IAddressBook.SamplePerson` property returns `Person` implementation and not `IPerson` interface, so your attempt to return `IPerson` will not work.

Either mock the `Person` class

```
var personMock = Substitute.For<Person>();
var addressBookMock = Substitute.For<IAddressBook>();
addressBookMock.SamplePerson.Returns(personMock);
```

or return an actual instance.

```
var person = new Person();
var addressBookMock = Substitute.For<IAddressBook>();
addressBookMock.SamplePerson.Returns(person);
```